# if statement, SSH and executing remote commands

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm writing some code that currently SSH to several servers in turn and remotely tests to see if a process is running.  The end goal is for me to receive an email alert if the process is not running.  I have that much working.

However, I also want a warning if the SSH connection fails.  Trouble is, no matter what I try, I cannot get it to work with my current code of if, the, else.

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="/root/scripts/sysmon_server_lists.txt"
identity="/root/.ssh/sysmon"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,

while read -r server searchtxt;
do
        if [ ! -z $server ]
        then
                if [ `ssh -n -q -t -i $identity root@$server "ps -ef | grep $searchtxt | grep -v grep | wc -l"` -gt 0 ]
                        then
                                echo "Process is running on $server."
                        else
                                echo "Process is not running on $server."
                        fi

                echo "Server is $server"
                echo "Searchtext is $searchtxt"
                echo " "
                echo "-----"
                echo " "
        fi
        done < $filename

IFS=$OLDIFS
echo "Finished"

exit 0
```

Comment: Don't test the output from `ssh` locally. Test it on the remote end and exit with a success or error status as appropriate. Then use that error status as your indicator (this also gets you indication of ssh failure).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to check if a process is running is to use `pkill -0`. You can check its return value directly in the `if` statement, getting rid of the need for the brackets `[ ]` and backticks `` `...` ``.

```
if ssh -nqti "$identity" root@"$server" pkill -0f "$searchtxt"; then
    echo "Process is running on $server."
else
    echo "Process is not running on $server." >&2
fi
```

This will conveniently fail if either the `ssh` or the `pkill` commands fail.

Another improvement you could make would be to override `$IFS` only for the duration of the `read` command. This would let you get rid of the code to save and restore it.

```
while IFS=, read -r server searchtxt; do
    ...
done
```